# Entity framework's big migration file causing failure to publish changes onto live server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

After a number of changes I made while developing, that includes some DB migrations as well. When i try publishing them to Production server it throws following error.

> The transaction log for database 'XXXX' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I tried pointing my development evironment to production DB and ran `Update-Database -Verbose -TargetMigration PendingMigration_2`, same result but this time I know the culprit migration that causing the filure.

It's nothing but number of columns that needs adding in an existing table.

```
public partial class fields_added_for_UKAS_calcert : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "UKAS_readings_taken_status", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0));
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_m1_1", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_m1_2", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_e2", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_f1", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "make", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "device_range", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0));
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

My limitations are that this WebApp is deployed on a shared server on GoDaddy. I can't change the DB `Transaction log size` nor I can change the `Recovery Mode` of the DB.

Is it possible to break this huge migration into smaller chunks that would be acceptable for the target server. Or any solution would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean is to break the migration, is {x} add columns per migration, then build the migration by adding {x} columns, then add {x} columns again then build migration, then till complete.

```
public partial class fields_added_for_UKAS_calcert_part1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "UKAS_readings_taken_status", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0));
        AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_m1_1", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }

public partial class fields_added_for_UKAS_calcert_part2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_m1_2", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Asset_Calcert", "weight_class_e2", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }
```